# Vertical space before and after titles in ACRO package (titleskip)

Tags: tocloft, acro

I am using `\acro` package, i would like to know the option in `\tocloft` or other tool for controlling the space before and after each class title, my MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
 only-used = false,
  first-style=default,%
    hyperref = true,
    %list-heading = section,
    group-citation = true,
    label = true,
only-used = false,
short-format = {\scshape},
extra-style = default,
            list-style =  longtable-rev
            }   
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainlanguage[calendar=gregorian, numerals=maghrib, locale=morocco, abjadjimnotail=true]{arabic}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Ligatures=TeX]{Amiri}

            \DeclareAcronym{ny}{
  short = NY, %{\textit{NY}\acdot} if you want to add a point after and make it italic
long  = New York ,
class = abbrev
}
\DeclareAcronym{alpha}{
short = {$\alpha $} ,
long  = Example ,
sort  = y ,
class = nomencl
} 
\begin{document}
\begin{LTR}
\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name= \Huge Symbols list]
\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=\Huge acronyms]
\end{LTR}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `acro` per default just uses `\chapter*` followed by a description list...

Comment: thank you  @clemens I am sorry i didn't understand what do you mean. Would you mind clarifying your idea? I would like to mention that  this MWE shows a reasonable space, but in my whole document shows a big space around 3 cm.